# Map full content path into a domain name and a subpath

Tags: aem, sling

[This blog](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration) presents a sample Sling Mappings configuration that maps paths like `/content/geometrixx/en/...` into URL `http://geometrixx.com/...`. Is it possible to prepare a similar configuration that adds an additional path part just after the domain? I'd like to map:

```
/content/geometrixx/en/...
```

into

```
http://mycompany.com/geometrixx/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to nest one `sling:Mapping` node into another and if you don't have the `sling:match` property, the nested node name will be treated as a subpath. Sample configuration may look like this:

```
{
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:OrderedFolder",
    "mycompany_com_geometrixx": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
        "sling:match": "mycompany.com/geometrixx$",
        "sling:internalRedirect": ["/content/geometrixx/en.html"],
    },
    "mycompany.com": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
        "geometrixx": {
            "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
            "sling:internalRedirect": "/content/geometrixx/en"
        }
    }
}
```

The first mapping (`mycompany_com_geometrixx`) is responsible for mapping this exact path:

```
http://mycompany.com/geometrixx
```

into the `en.html` webpage, so the user doesn't have to provide `.html` extension at the end of it. The second mapping `mycompany.com` contains nested `geometrixx` mapping to configure the following URL pattern: `http://mycompany.com/geometrixx/...`